# Facebook photo sharer link?

Tags: facebook, share, photos

Is there any link that when its clicked automaticly redirects you to a photo upload page?

Similar to this sharer but for photos:
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a Facebook plugin, then the answer is **no**. Here is the [list of all plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) provided by Facebook.